# How to pass arguments in the Hardhat revertedWith

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, solidity, chai, hardhat

I'm writing tests for a Lottery contract and I'm testing a scenario that should fail with the custom error. I'm still learning blockchain so any help would be appreciated.

below is the solidity code:

```
 function performUpkeep(
        bytes calldata /* performData*/
    ) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane, //
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }
```

This is my test script:

```
describe("performUpkeep", function () {
              it("can only run if checkupkeep is true", async () => {
                  await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                  await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() + 1])
                  await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] })
                  const tx = await raffle.performUpkeep("0x")
                  assert(tx)
              })
              it("reverts if checkup is false", async () => {
                  
                  await expect(raffle.performUpkeep("0x")).to.be.revertedWith(
                      `Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(0,0,0)`
                  )
              })
          })
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(0,0,0), but other exception was thrown: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(0, 0, 0)'
```

Both double quotes and backticks produce the same error.

It was difficult for me to find any examples on chai site https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html#revert-with-message and also on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A simple interpolation fix fixed this issue.

```
await expect(raffle.performUpkeep("0x")).to.be.revertedWith(
                  `Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(${0}, ${0}, ${0})`
```

If you do not space them out in between, the error will persist.

source: [github discussion forum](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/3736)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).